# Android Base Activity's onActivityResult() result need from child activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My Base Activity code -

```
public abstract class SpeechToTextActivity extends Activity {

private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;



/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 * */
public void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
```

}

Now I need the result of onActivityResult() from another child activity which extends SpeechToTextActivity  .

Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `onActivityResult` in the child, and retrieve the result. The code is the same. If the child is responsible to manage the data, you should remove the case from the parent and have the code just in the derived class(es)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, can you please explain " If the child is responsible to manage the data, you should remove the case from the parent and have the code just in the derived class(es)" or give some example code.

Comment: does the super class need to handle the object you are retrieving from the bundle? If the answer is not, then is the derived type, the concrete instance in your case, that handles the data. So you don't need it in to retrieve it also in the super class

Comment: Thanks, I just commented the super class onActivityResult() body and keep this same on sub class. Thanks +1 also for you.